# Eclipse XML Schema content assistance when workink with foreign attributes

Tags: xml, eclipse, xsd

my question is about making the Eclise XML Schema Editor aware (that is to say, able to propose me assistance on completion ...) of foreign XML attributes coming from another Schema, with different target namespace.

here is a dummy example, just for understanding :
let's say we have a Schema that defines a simple Book class in the namespace http://www.example.org/books

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/books" elementFormDefault="qualified" vc:minVersion="1.1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/books">
<xs:complexType name="Book">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Author" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Editor" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="ISBN" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

and a second Schema, likely coming from a third party provider, defining a collection of interesting attributes to manage a library stock, within the vendor's namespace http://www.example.org/biblio

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/biblio"
elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/biblio">
<xs:attribute name="mediaType" type="tns:Media"/>
<xs:attribute name="storageLocation" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:simpleType name="Media">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="BOOK"></xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="DVD"></xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="MAGAZINE"></xs:enumeration>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

From that point, my organization decides that it is interesting to incorporate the mediaType attributes into the Book Schema in order to document / annotate this schema in a fashion that complies "somehow" with the vendors definitions.

I've read that it is possible to incorporate foreign attributes into any xsd type definitions parts (complexType, simpleType, sequence ...).

So I modify the Books schema to make it "aware" of the biblio namespace :

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/books"
elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/books"
xmlns:bilio="http://www.example.org/biblio">
```

and I want to annotate the complexType Book with the mediaType attribute as follows :

```
<xs:complexType name="Book" bilio:mediaType="BOOK">
```

So I end up with the following schema :

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/books"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/books"
    xmlns:bilio="http://www.example.org/biblio">
    <xs:complexType name="Book" bilio:mediaType="BOOK">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="Author" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="Editor" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="ISBN" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Just Great ! Eclipse validator does not even complain. But the content assistant is not able to propose me neither the attributes in the prefix biblio: nor the values of the biblio:mediaType !

How can it be so complicated to make it aware that the attributes are in the other schema and propose me the possible attributes / values ? I ve tried by creating a Catalog Entry for the biblio schema, to import the schema, even if it does not make sense for me, ... so I am just stuck trying to edit manually my schema.

Please note : my purpose is to stay at the Schema Level, I a not asking about how to make those attributes visible in some XML Instances of that schema (and so the reason why xsd imports does not make sense for me)
In fact I don't really care about instance level, let's assume I am using XSD as a convenient UML-like modeling tool, but don't care about creating XML files with it (even if its not exactly that ...)